# Server side(DB) aggregation in BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Bigtable for aggregates

I am trying to run a range query on top of BigTable. My ultimate objective is to get a sum of one of the column qualifiers, but from all the reading I have done, seems aggregations aren't possible in bigtable. Currently only possibility is to get all the data at client side, and do the aggregations there. But this approach does not be optimal for aggregation based patterns . Is there any known workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you cannot get aggregations for Bigtable server side. There are a few approaches to get this information and they depend on the size of your database, how frequently you need the information, and development factors.

As you mentioned, one approach is to query all the data client side and aggregate it that way. You can stream the results, so you don't have to keep it all in memory that way, but this won't be very performant.

A similar, but more performant approach would be to write an ETL pipeline – I'd recommend via Beam/Dataflow. You can query the whole table and parallelize the aggregation. The time to run this will depend on your table size, query and aggregation needs. You would have to write code using the [Bigtable Dataflow connector in Java](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java) which might have a learning curve if you don't use them regularly, but for a simple aggregation, the code won't be too different than whatever you are doing locally.

A final option is to use Bigtable as an [external table in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/create-bigtable-external-table#bq). This is a pretty low/no-code solution. You'll have to set up a definition file for your Bigtable table and then import it into BigQuery. Then you can run full-table aggregations on your table and get the information you want. Be mindful of this option since it can have performance impacts on your serving data with Bigtable. If it's not something you need to do regularly it could be fine. You could also export the results of some of your queries to their own BigQuery tables, so once you have the data stored, you can requery it without having to touch Bigtable – this data would get stale, so you would need to update it regularly if you want the freshest data.